# TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument "name"

Tags: python, google-api

The seemingly simple code below throws the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "search.py", line 48, in
>   
>       pageToken=page_token).execute()   File "C:\Users\Choi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py",
>   line 716, in method
>
> raise TypeError('Got an unexpected keyword argument "%s"' % name) TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument "name"

Code:

```
scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('pyGD-eadb4d7ba057.json', scope)
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
drive_service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
page_token = None
print('While START::::')
while True:
    response = drive_service.files().list(name = 'hello',
                                            spaces='drive',
                                            fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                            pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
        #Process change
        print('RESULT::::')
        print ('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken',None)
    if page_token is None:
        break
```

What am I doing wrong please? Thank you.

Comment: The `list()` call does not have a `name` argument.

Comment: ``name`` cannot be directly used to the request body of ``drive_service.files().list()``. If you want to retrieve files which have the filename of ``hello``, modify from ``name = 'hello'`` to ``q='name = \'hello\''``. If you want to retrieve files which include ``hello`` in the filename, modify from ``name = 'hello'`` to ``q='name contains \'hello\''``. If you want to retrieve files which include ``hello`` in the contents, modify from ``name = 'hello'`` to ``q='fullText contains \'"hello"\''``. The document of about ``q`` is [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the trackback. Let's have a look at [googleapiclient/discovery.py](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/discovery.py)

```
def method(self, **kwargs):
# Don't bother with doc string, it will be over-written by createMethod.

    for name in six.iterkeys(kwargs):
        if name not in parameters.argmap:
>>          raise TypeError('Got an unexpected keyword argument "%s"' % name)
```

The error was raised here. You have a wrong argument called `name`.

[According to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters), the query should be in argument `q`.

```
response = drive_service.files().list(q="name='hello'",
                                        spaces='drive',
                                        fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                        pageToken=page_token).execute()
```